# How to custom the display order of polynomial in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

For example, I have

```
A = a*c*b + d*c*b + d*c*t
```

Where b and t are more like variables and a,c,d are more like parameters.
It would be displayed as

```
a b c + b c d + c d t
```

what I want is let it be displayed as

```
a c b + d c b + d c t
```

Where b and t are in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Dirty trick:

```
a*c*b + d*c*b + d*c*t /. Thread[# -> (Interpretation[ToString[#], #] & /@ #)] &@{b, t}
```

> ```
> a c b + c d b + c d t
> ```